# From where this value comes from

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am completely new to Angualr, and I can not understand where this value is calculated ( 11 - 20 )
[image]

`pageSizeOptions` is an array of numbers [10,20]

`length` is length

but where this value comes from? because it is not calculated correctly and I do not know why

```
<mat-paginator [length]="resultsLength" [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" showFirstLastButtons
    (page)="changePage($event)"></mat-paginator>
```

I had this issue when searching and it was fixed by adding to this code

```
this.subscription = this.inputChanged
  .pipe(
    tap(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0) //this line
  ).subscribe(() => {
   this.refreshMatchings(this.configurator);
  });
```

But I have a box with filters which refetches too, but it has the same issue and I do not where to put `tap(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0)` this line to fix it

Comment: This could be confusing at the start, I agree. In Object Oriented Programming language, when you declare variables within the class and if you wish to access them, you have to use this.variableName. Here 'this' is nothing but the scope of current class (component, directive or service). Since we write class for almost everything in Angular, Object Oriented paradigm is involved and you need to use 'this' to access member variables and methods! Eventually you'll get gist of this 

Comment: Have you try setting the `pageIndex` to 0 after calling `refreshMatchings`?